# C# Combine Two Lists With Overlapping Data

Tags: c#, .net, linq, list, overlapping

If I have 2 lists of strings

```
List<string> history = new List<string>(){ "AA", "BB", "CC", "AA" };
List<string> potentialNew = new List<string>(){ "CC", "AA", "DD", "EE", "FF", "AA"};
```

I need a way to combine the lists while preventing "overlap" and retaining the same ordering. So, in the example above, there would be a combined list that is:

```
AA, BB, CC, AA, DD, EE, FF, AA
```

In other words only **DD, EE, FF, and AA** are added to the `history` list.

I've been trying to figure this out for a few days now, and countless searches have yielded no solution. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: what would be your expected output if a `"BB"` comes after `"FF", "AA"` in the second list?

Comment: If the second list is CC, AA, DD, EE, FF, AA, BB the expected output would be AA, BB, CC, AA, DD, EE, FF, AA, BB

Comment: List1 `"AA", "BB", "CC", "AA" ` and list2 `"CC", "AA", "DD", "EE", "FF", "AA","BB"`

Comment: The combined list would be "AA", "BB", "CC", "AA", "DD", "EE", "FF", "AA", "BB"

Comment: So be Frank; what is the logic behind elimination of items from second list?

Comment: The application of this combining of lists is logging a game's chat log that is being parsed every so often with OCR and to keep a running log of chat messages.

So, there's a list of "old" messages (the history) and then a list of "potential new" messages. However, only the actual new messages should be added to the "history" list.

Comment: So, in this example, the first 2 items of **potentialNew** aren't added because they're already at the end of **history**, but the rest of the values in **potentialNew** are.

Comment: I have updated the answer could you please take a look and let me know is that you ware looking for

Comment: So you say its a game chat log and you want to eliminate the same string in potentialNew list because you assume its the same chat being repeated. Now question is what if the user sends the same message say like 20 times?? according to your logic you will definitely loose some messages assuming its a old one..

Comment: @chutch1122 Let me know if my answer meets your requirement.

Answer (score 5):

This will give you the expected output for the set of given input as you mentioned in the question:

```
 List<string> history = new List<string>() { "AA", "BB", "CC", "AA" };
 List<string> potentialNew = new List<string>() { "CC", "AA", "DD", "EE", "FF" };
 var result = history.Concat(potentialNew.Where(x => !history.Contains(x)).ToList());
```

The [`.Concat()`](http://www.dotnetperls.com/list-concat) method allows you to Concatenates two list. we are extracting particular items from the `potentialNew` that are not present in the first List and concat them with the first list.

**Update** : As per our discussion I Came in a conclusion that you are looking for something like the following:

```
string lastItem = history.Last();
   int lastIndexToCheck=history.Count-2,i=0;
   for (; i < potentialNew.Count - 1; i++)
       {
          if (potentialNew[i] == lastItem && potentialNew[i - 1] == history[lastIndexToCheck])
              {
                 break;
              }
       }
       history.AddRange(potentialNew.Skip(i+1).ToList());
```

Now history will contains the required set of elements.

Comment: I should have mentioned it in my question, but let's say I have "AA" again after "FF" in the second list. "AA" would then also need to be added to the new list. (I've edited my question to reflect this)

Comment: The application of this combining of lists is a game's chat log. The chat log that is being parsed every so often with OCR and I'm keeping a running log of chat entries so I need to compare what I already have logged with new chat entries.

Comment: Doesn't seem like a good way of doing a chat log.  Wouldn't it be better to append the entries as you receive them? Using async? With this design as your chat log grows you application will always get slower.

Comment: The game is a different application (that I did not make), otherwise I would do that. I only need to compare against the last 20 or so entries anyway, since I'm just checking for new values. Right?

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        List<string> history = new List<string>(){ "AA", "BB", "CC", "AA" };
        List<string> potentialNew = new List<string>(){ "CC", "AA", "DD", "EE", "FF" };
        // make lists equal length

        foreach(var x in history.ConcatOverlap(potentialNew)){
            Console.WriteLine(x);
        }
    }


}

public static class Ext{
    public static IEnumerable<string> ConcatOverlap(this List<string> history, List<string> potentialNew){
        var hleng = history.Count();
        var pleng = potentialNew.Count();
        if(pleng > hleng) history = history.Concat(Enumerable.Range(1, pleng - hleng).Select(x => string.Empty)).ToList();
        if(hleng > pleng) potentialNew = Enumerable.Range(1, hleng - pleng).Select(x => string.Empty).Concat(potentialNew).ToList();


        var zipped = history.Zip(potentialNew, (a,b)=> new {First=a,Next=b, Equal = (a.Equals(b) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(a) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(b))});
        var count = 0;
        var max = pleng > hleng ? pleng : hleng;
        Console.WriteLine("Max " + max);
        while(zipped.Any(x => !x.Equal) && count < max - 1){
            count++;
            potentialNew.Insert(0,string.Empty);
            history.Add(string.Empty);
            zipped = history.Zip(potentialNew, (a,b)=> new {First=a,Next=b, Equal = (a.Equals(b) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(a) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(b))});
        }
        return zipped.Select(x => string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.First) ? x.Next : x.First);
    }
}
```

After a little more consideration:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> ConcatOverlap<T>(this IEnumerable<T> head, IEnumerable<T> tail){

    var skip = 0;
    var hLen = head.Count();
    while(head.Skip(skip).Zip(tail, (a,b) => a.Equals(b)).Any(x => !x) && skip < hLen){
        skip++;
    }

    return head.Take(skip).Concat(tail);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var history = new List<string>() { "AA", "BB", "CC", "AA" };
var potentialNew = new List<string>() { "CC", "AA", "DD", "EE", "FF" };

// Get the min. number of items to compare that 2 lists
for (int count = Math.Min(history.Count(), potentialNew.Count()); count >= 0; count--)
{
    // Get the items from the back of history list, and get the items from potential list
    // Compare them by SequenceEqual()
    if (history.Skip(history.Count() - count).Take(count).SequenceEqual(potentialNew.Take(count)))
    {
        // Add the items to the result if found. It must be the greatest common part
        return history.Concat(potentialNew.Skip(count));
    }
}
```

[.Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/nopwGd)

Answer (score 0):

This seems very easy:

```
List<string> history = new List<string>(){ "AA", "BB", "CC", "AA" };
List<string> potentialNew = new List<string>(){ "CC", "AA", "DD", "EE", "FF", "AA"};

potentialNew.Aggregate(history, (h, p) =>
{
    if (!h.Skip(h.Count - 2).Contains(p))
    {
        h.Add(p);
    }
    return h;
});
```

The result is `history` contains:

```
AA 
BB 
CC 
AA 
DD 
EE 
FF 
AA
```

Comment: Breaks if the potinetialNew is `"AA", "CC", "AA", "DD", "EE", "FF", "AA" `, the Desired output for this is `"AA", "BB", "CC", "AA" , "CC", "AA", "DD", "EE", "FF", "AA"`. But yours still give the same output as in your answer

Comment: @Reddy - Why is that the desired output?

Comment: lol, thats how crazy his logic is.. So what he says is the string array is actually a continuous  chat log, And he gets possible duplicates of the same message in next new list. So he wants to remove the possible duplicates from the new list. So coming to the desired output if you look my input for the second list you can notice that `AA` would be the only one which might be a duplicate. As the messages will be in order.  Still his desired output is not right. If say like 20 messages are same the OP's desired logic will omit few. but thats what he wants...

Comment: @Reddy - Sorry, I still don't understand what the requirement is. This is sounding bizarre.

Comment: Yes it is bizarre for sure

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how good this is performance wise but I built a logic to achieve what you wanted. It is open for anyone to tweek to make it more cleaner.

```
List<string> history = new List<string>() { "AA", "BB", "CC", "AA" };
List<string> potentialNew = new List<string>() { "CC", "AA", "DD", "EE", "FF", "AA" };

var result = ProcessChatLog(history,potentialNew);
//pass these two list to a function to process the chat log
```

The Core logic is in here.

```
 public List<string> ProcessChatLog(List<string> history, List<string> potentialNew)
    {
        var lastChat = history.Last();  
        var lastChatIndex = history.Count - 1;
        var allIndexWithLastChat = potentialNew.Select((c, i) => new { chat = c, Index = i })
                                   .Where(x => x.chat == lastChat)
                                   .Select(x => x.Index).Reverse().ToList();       

        List<int> IndexToClear = new List<int>();
        bool overlapFound = false;

        foreach (var index in allIndexWithLastChat)
        {
            if (!overlapFound)
            {
                int hitoryChatIndex = lastChatIndex;
                IndexToClear.Clear();
                for (int i = index; i > -1; i--)
                {
                    if (potentialNew[i] == history[hitoryChatIndex])
                    {
                        IndexToClear.Add(i);
                        if (i == 0)
                        {
                            overlapFound = true;
                            break;
                        }
                        hitoryChatIndex--;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                IndexToClear.Clear();
                break;
            }                             
        }

        if(IndexToClear.Count >0)
        {
            potentialNew.RemoveRange(IndexToClear.Min(), IndexToClear.Count);   
        }

        return history.Concat(potentialNew).ToList();
    }
```

Here are some of the results

```
  history = { "AA", "BB", "CC", "AA" }
  potentialNew = { "CC", "AA", "DD", "EE", "FF", "AA"}

  Result = { "AA", "BB","CC", "AA", "DD", "EE", "FF", "AA"}
```

---

```
  history = { "AA", "BB","AA", "CC", "AA" }
  potentialNew = { "AA","CC", "AA", "DD", "EE", "FF", "AA"}

  Result = { "AA", "BB","AA","CC", "AA", "DD", "EE", "FF", "AA"}
```

---

```
  history = { "AA", "BB", "CC", "AA" }
  potentialNew = { "CC", "AA", "CC", "AA", "FF", "AA"}

  Result = { "AA", "BB","CC", "AA", "CC", "AA", "FF", "AA"}
```

---

```
  history = { "AA", "BB", "CC", "AA" }
  potentialNew = {"AA", "CC", "AA", "DD", "EE", "FF", "AA" }

  Result = { "AA", "BB","CC", "AA", "CC", "AA", "DD", "EE", "FF", "AA" }
```

Let me know if this helps.

**But I still say this is not a good desired output which you want**. Because what if the chat contains same message 20 times and assume you get it in 2 lists with 11 and 9 items respectively. Now according to your desired output you will omit all 9 message new list as a possible duplicate and that a problem. So I say rather than this fix the solution would be to keep track of what messages are being passed in the chat log and take measures to not pass those in next log.. This way the logic and the accuracy will be maintained